# Silverlight styles for custom controls. Using the BasedOn property

Tags: silverlight, controls

I had been previously using the DefaultStyleKey setting to set my datagrid's style, but now i want to extend one style with the BasedOn property of another.  So now I have two styles with the same Type, and I must be more specifc than simply setting the DefaultStyleKey.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to access the generic.xaml file to get at the style's I've created.

There must be a workaround for when you don't want to use DefaultStyleKey, and need to access your styles from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
base.OnApplyTemplate();
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
rd.Source = new Uri("/CustomControl;component/Themes/generic.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Style style = rd["StyleKey"] as Style;
}
```

'CustomControl' is the name of your project, and StyleKey the Key for the style you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

So why can't you extend your datagrid as well, create a new class and use default style key as new type and in your generic.xaml you can create a new style based on your previous style.

But in siverlight, we create one base style as named style and we inherit styles from it.

```
<style x:Key="BaseDataGrid"

<style TargetType="MyGrid1" 
       BasedOn="BaseDataGrid"

<style TargetType="MyGrid2" 
       BasedOn="BaseDataGrid"
```

Comment: Yes, that is one solution, but I wanted to avoid completely recreating a style for a datagrid, when all i needed was to tweak one parameter on the existing.